# How can I divide a database table into two tables on the basis of columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table with ten columns:

```
name, id, colg, schol, add, no, subject, marks, surname, lectures
```

Can I split this table into two separate tables without any data loss like this?

table one:

```
name, id, colg, schol, add, no
```

table two:

```
subject, marks, surname, lectures
```

Comment: Why would you wish to do so? And if you were to do so, you would need a link between the 2 tables, so table 2 would also need an id column, which needs to correspand to that of table 1

Comment: You should explain why you want to do this, and what you wish to achieve by splitting this into two tables? Also, should these tables relate to each other?

Comment: Yes, you can easily do this. In general, this is called partitioning. In your specific case, it's called vertical partitioning. The answer from @shaunhusain demonstrates the basic mechanics of this.

Comment: And **Why** would you want to do this? Perhaps you may only need to save data into the second table a fraction of the time. Vertical partitioning can also radically speed up searches when many queries only need information from the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE old_table (name VARCHAR(255), id BIGINT, colg VARCHAR(255), schol VARCHAR(255), addit VARCHAR(255), no VARCHAR(255), subject VARCHAR(255), marks VARCHAR(255), surname VARCHAR(255), lectures VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO old_table VALUES("shaun", 1234, "DePaul University", "Computing and Digital Media", "something", "something", "some subject", "A", "Husain","no thank you");

mysql> SELECT * FROM old_table;
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
| name  | id   | colg              | schol                       | addit     | no        | subject      | marks | surname | lectures     |
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
| shaun | 1234 | DePaul University | Computing and Digital Media | something | something | some subject | A     | Husain  | no thank you |
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

CREATE TABLE table1 (name VARCHAR(255), id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, colg VARCHAR(255), schol VARCHAR(255), addit VARCHAR(255), no VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE table2 (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, subject VARCHAR(255), marks VARCHAR(255), surname VARCHAR(255), lectures VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO table1 (name,id,colg,schol,addit,no) SELECT name,id,colg,schol,addit,no from old_table;
INSERT INTO table2 (id,subject,marks,surname,lectures) SELECT id,subject,marks,surname,lectures from old_table;

mysql> select * from table1;
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| name  | id   | colg              | schol                       | addit     | no        |
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| shaun | 1234 | DePaul University | Computing and Digital Media | something | something |
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2;
+------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
| id   | subject      | marks | surname | lectures     |
+------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
| 1234 | some subject | A     | Husain  | no thank you |
+------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on (table1.id=table2.id);
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
| name  | id   | colg              | schol                       | addit     | no        | id   | subject      | marks | surname | lectures     |
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
| shaun | 1234 | DePaul University | Computing and Digital Media | something | something | 1234 | some subject | A     | Husain  | no thank you |
+-------+------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+------+--------------+-------+---------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just have to create a one-to-one relationship between the tables.  You can do this by making a unique primary key on each table, where the primary key of the second table is also a foreign key of the first table's primary key.

**Table #1**

```
PK_ID      (primary key)
name
id
colg
schol
add
no
```

**Table #2**

```
PK_ID      (primary key, foreign key to Table #1)
subject
marks
surname
lectures
```

So the steps would be simply:

1. Create two new tables with the structure above)
2. Insert all records from the existing table into table #1
3. Insert all records from the existing table into table #2, with a join on table #1 to get the foreign key

(Note that you could also use one of the columns in the existing table as the primary key, *id* for example, as long as it's unique.)

Comment: This is true I believe the OP may be looking for how to INSERT INTO using a SELECT possibly?

Comment: dbasename my question is that how to divide records in master to two tables on the basis of field name . After that i can you primary key and foreign key concept .

Comment: yes shaunhusain ....... i want to ask how insert records in two tables from master table..

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html < basically you would do this twice, once for each new table, then you can clean up the old table, but you want to make sure you maintain a link between table 1 and table 2 hence the primary/foreign key concept, be sure to back up your master table :)

Comment: @shaunhusain i got that but first tell me how can i insert records in sub tables..

Comment: first insert in the main table then get its newly inserted id then insert in the sub table with newly inserted id

Comment: No problem I was trying to get an example working but using mysql at the command line isn't forgiving I'm spoiled with phpmyadmin